# SaSS loops for usage

Tags: css, sass

I would like to create classes, that apply specific margin to my blocks. For example:

```
 .standard-margin-top {margin-top:10px;}
 .standard-margin-bottom {margin-bottom: 10px;}
 .small-margin-top {...}

 ...

 .large-margin-left {...}
```

And so on. There are 20 classes together (each direction with `xs`, `small`, `standard`, `large` and `no`). Is it possible to simplify this with sass loops? I'm pretty new with it.

I've read, how to create loops with numbers but I have no idea, what should I do here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@each` loop.

There are two collections of sizes and margin directions: `$sizes` and `$directions`. Then we use `@each` loop to go through these collections and generate css selectors. Use `#{}` to insert variable value as string.

[Demo on sassmeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/2196c39ac6acad3cec0357d8caeaab7e)

```
$sizes: xs, small, standard, large, no;
$directions: top, right, bottom, left;

@each $size in $sizes {
  @each $direction in $directions {
    .#{$size}-margin-#{$direction} {
      margin-#{$direction}: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a sass list type variable

```
$types :(
      type : 'small',
      margins: (
         top : 10px,
         left: 10px,
         right : 10px,
         bottom: 10px
      )),
      (
      type : 'standard', 
      margins: (
        top : 10px,
         left: 10px,
         right : 10px,
         bottom: 10px,
      ));
@function get-theme-name($theme){
  @return map-get($theme, 'type');
};
@each $type in $types {   
  $theme-name : get-theme-name($type);
  @each $key in map-keys($type) {
    @if ($key == 'margins') {
      $values : map-get($type, 'margins');
      @each $itemKey in map-keys($values) {
        .#{$theme-name}-margin-#{$itemKey} {
          margin-#{$itemKey} :map-get($values, $itemKey);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check the demo here [Sass Meister](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/36516b61cc15006993f99d788e9c3a08)

Comment: Just one typo. Do you mean "margin" instead "color"  here? `color :map-get($values, $itemKey)`