# Take number from class using Sass

Tags: css, sass

Having the class name 'class-name-X' (where X might be a number from 0 to 9) I'd like to create an specific class for all of them like:

```
.class-name-{X} {
  height: {X} + 'px';
}
```

Is that possible? I know that using arrays it's but this comes from the JS to the HTML so on the CSS I only get the class name

Comment: Help us a little more - Confirm that your code block is in scss and that you want the sass compiler to make 10 different classes in the css file.

Comment: Perhaps this question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591573/sass-loops-for-usage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a variable in SASS depending on the selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112238/set-a-variable-in-sass-depending-on-the-selector)

Comment: I have no code at all on my scss. Everything is done by JS and HTML.
The first link is using an array. I know that way but as commented I have array at all, the html has all the variables already.
The second link is repeating the variables with colours on different blocks, that's not what I'm looking for. I just want one block

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`@for`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_for) directive to iterate through numbers (say 0 through 9 in your use case), and use [string interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Interpolation_____) to inject the current index as part of the class name, and also to the `width` property:

```
$start: 0;
$end: 9;

@for $i from $start through $end {
  .class-name--#{$i} {
    width: #{$i}px;
  }
}
```

Remember that SASS is a pre-compile language, so you will need to compile it and then use that generated CSS for your page ;)